# How bad can the second derivative of a convex function be?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, convexity, convex-analysis

One can easily construct an example of a measurable function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the following property:

$$\label{p}\tag{P}
f\notin L^1(I),\ \mbox{for each interval}\ I\subset (a,b).
$$

We know that a convex function $g:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is locally Lipschitz and its second derivative $g''$ exists a.e. $x\in (a,b)$.

> Can we find a increasing convex function $g$, such that $g''$ satisfies the property \ref{p}?

If the answer is negative

> What can we say about the set of intervals $I$ for which $g''\notin L^1(I)$?

Remark: I've asked a similar question on Math.stack with no answer.

Comment: Hint: If $g$ is a convex function, then $g'$ is an increasing function.  So an equivalent question is: How bad can be the derivative of an increasing function?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Following your question  The derivative of an increasing  function is a Borel measure $\mu$  on the interval, so the question would be how bad  such a measure could be?  I think that $g''$ would be the  density of the absolutely continuous part of  $\mu$. This would be $L^1$ on each interval $I$ such that $\mu(I)<\infty$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu ... correct.  $g''$ (in the sense of a function) is in $L^1$ on every closed interval contained in the domain of $g$.  If the OP means $g''$ is the distributional sense, he/she should see the answer of Denis.

Comment: I mean g'' in the sense of a function @GeraldEdgar.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second derivative of a convex function, in the distributional sense, is a non-negative bounded measure. And conversely. If this measure $\mu$ contains a sum $\sum_na_n\delta_{x=x_n}$, where $(x_n)_n$ is dense and $a_n>0$, $\sum_na_n<\infty$, then $\mu|_I\not\in L^1(I)$ for every non-void open interval $I$. The corresponding $g$ is an example for the first question.

On the other hand $g''$ can be decomposed uniquely into a singular part $\mu_s$ and a part $\mu_a<\!<{\cal Leb}$. Because $\mu_s,\mu_a$ are non-negative, we have
$$\int_c^dd\mu_a\le|g''|<\infty,$$
at least if $a<c<d<b$.
Therefore $\mu_a\in L^1(I)$ for every $I\subset\!\subset(a,b)$.